# How to check if any of the fields of a model are null or empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, model

I have a model, `$userModel`. I want to check if **any** of the fields for this model are empty or `null`.

At the moment I am doing it with a big if statement.

```
if(!empty($userModel->name) && !empty($userModel->address) ... && !empty($userModel->email))
{
   // All fields have values
}
```

This way works, but if later I need to add another field to the model, then I need to go back to the if and add another `&&` condition there.

How can I do this in one check?

Is there something like: `$userModel::model()->areAllFieldsFilled();`

---

Extra info: The model is already saved in the db, and there is no need for user input. This is just me checking how complete a particular model is, by no means will all these fields be required in the database, only a few. Things like `$userModel->bio` are usually left `null`.

**I want to avoid checking 5 to 10 fields. I don't want a giant if that has to be maintained when the model changes.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP allows you to [iterate over an object's properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php). The check for each property could be simplified using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
$allHaveValues = TRUE;
foreach ($userModel as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
       $allHaveValues = FALSE;
       break;
    }
}

if ($allHaveValues) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: `$userModel` is an `object`. This will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty()`

```
if(!empty($userModel->name)) { .. }
```

[empty() DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

**Update**

```
$modelData = array($userModel->name, $userModel->address, $userModel->email);
if(!in_array('', $modelData) && !in_array(null, $modelData)) { .. }
```

[in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Or you can use `array_intersect` -

```
if(empty(array_intersect(array('', null), $modelData))) { .. }
```

[array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: That helps too, but I still want to avoid checking 5 to 10 fields. I don't want a giant `if` that has to be maintained when the model changes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need do it.

Everything you need - it just specify your validation rules.

For example:

```
<?php

class Brand extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'brand';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['name, country', 'on' => 'insert'],
            ['name', 'type', 'type' => 'string', 'on' => 'insert'],
            ['name', 'length', 'max' => 100, 'on' => 'insert'],
            ['name', 'type', 'type' => 'array', 'on' => 'search'],
            ['country', 'type', 'type' => 'string'],
            ['country', 'length', 'max' => 50],
        ];
    }
}
```

When you will use this model you'll just need validate this model by `$model->validate()` and if it fails - show errors with `$model->getErrors()`. Moreover you can specify what rules scenario you wish to use. For example: `$model->senario = 'search';` will be used validation rule `search` and property `name` should be array. But when scenario `insert` name should be string with length not more than 100.

In my example fields: name, country - required for insert (`['name, country', 'on' => 'insert']`).